# QGIS time manager - shapefile in edit mode?

Tags: qgis, shapefile, timemanager

In QGIS 2.18, shapefiles are not editable when loaded in the timeManager.
Is there a workaround?

Or do you know if this is available in more recent version?

The timestamps in the shapefile are set in seconds which by default refer to the seconds elapsed since 1/1/1970.

Comment: Are you mapping in geologic time? Shapefile s only support day resolution (no HHMMSS)

Comment: the time in the shapefile is set in seconds since a reference time which is by default 1/1/1970. the display works fine. my issue is that I cannot enable the edition tool when the shapefile is loaded in the timemanager.

Comment: Please put this information in the body of the question. The fact that you're using an integer field is probably relevant to the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The TimeManager plugin controls the editing of its layers when it's on.

So, just turn it off while you are not playing the sequence and that layers will be editable again.

**UPDATE:** In QGIS 3.4.2 the plugin doesn't block shapefile layers.

Comment: when I turn off the timemanger then all feature show up and finding the one that matches the time where i stop is not easy

Comment: Why isn't it easy to find the feature that matches the time where you stop? You can find a feature that with a certain attribute value by using the search function, or sorting the attribute table by the time field and scroll to the time you stopped at, or selecting by attribute.

Comment: Answer updated. And yes, you always can _Select Features by Expression_.

Comment: i confirmed shapefile layer are editable when loaded in timemanger in version 3.4.2